# is there any scriptella jruby script sample/example?

Tags: scriptella

I am new scriptella user.

Is there any sample or tutorial to use jruby 
as scripting language?

Thanks and Regards,

Manish

== updated after ejboy's suggesstions ==

- Copied jruby.jar (1.7.4) in lib.
- However scriptella failed with following exception.

Jun 14, 2013 9:31:36 AM  Script /bigdisk/work/cougar/code/leopard-monitor/analytics/kpoint_usage/scriptella/scripts/jruby_sample.xml execution failed.

```
/etl/script[1] failed: keySet
Location: /etl/script[1]
Jun 14, 2013 9:31:36 AM <SEVERE> Scriptella bug report. Submit to issue tracker.
Scriptella version: 1.1
Exception:
scriptella.execution.EtlExecutorException: /etl/script[1] failed: keySet Location: /etl/script[1]
    at scriptella.execution.EtlExecutor.execute(EtlExecutor.java:190)
    at scriptella.tools.launcher.EtlLauncher.execute(EtlLauncher.java:276)
    at scriptella.tools.launcher.EtlLauncher.launch(EtlLauncher.java:193)
    at scriptella.tools.launcher.EtlLauncher.main(EtlLauncher.java:321)
Caused by: scriptella.core.ExceptionInterceptor$ExecutionException: /etl/script[1] failed: keySet
    at scriptella.core.ExceptionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionInterceptor.java:44)
    at scriptella.core.Session.execute(Session.java:103)
    at scriptella.execution.EtlExecutor.execute(EtlExecutor.java:227)
    at scriptella.execution.EtlExecutor.execute(EtlExecutor.java:183)
    ... 3 more
```

Following is my xml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
  <description>
    use jruby as scripting language.
  </description>
  <connection id="script-jruby" driver="script" url="out/test-out.csv"> <!-- classpath="path/to/jar:path/to/jar2"> -->
     language=jruby
  </connection>
  <script connection-id="script-jruby">
    puts "Hello world - using jruby"
  </script>
</etl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the language property to jruby and make sure the required jars are available on classpath. You can either copy them to `<scriptella_home>/lib` directory or include in the connection declaration:

```
<connection id="script" driver="script" classpath="path/to/jar:path/to/jar2">
   language=jruby
</connection>
```

Comment: Hi it failed with /etl/script[1] failed: keySet. Please see updated question for details. Thanks. Manish